# Visual Basic - "If" Statements Not Showing Result In Label

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm working on an assignment where the program needs to calculate and display the total cost for shipping a package, based on weight and whether it is being shipped to Continental U.S., Alaska, or Hawaii. When I click the Calculate button, though, the label that is supposed to display the total is left blank. I've looked through this and tried placing the calculation in different parts/at the end of the "If" statements. Here's what I have thus far, any help would be appreciated:

```
Dim decWeight As Decimal
Dim decTotalCost As Decimal
Dim decDestination As Decimal
Dim decRate As Decimal

If IsNumeric(txtWeight.Text) Then

    decWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text)


    If decWeight <= 30 > 0 Then

        If radContinental.Checked Then
            decDestination = 1
        ElseIf radHawaii.Checked Then
            decDestination = 1.2
        ElseIf radAlaska.Checked Then
            decDestination = 1.26
        End If

        If decWeight <= 2 Then
            decRate = 3.69
        ElseIf decWeight <= 4 > 2 Then
            decRate = 4.86
        ElseIf decWeight <= 6 > 4 Then
            decRate = 5.63
        ElseIf decWeight <= 8 > 6 Then
            decRate = 5.98
        ElseIf decWeight <= 10 > 8 Then
            decRate = 6.28
        ElseIf decWeight <= 30 > 10 Then
            decRate = 15.72
        End If

        decTotalCost = decRate * decDestination
        lblTotalCost.Text = decTotalCost.ToString("C")

    ElseIf decWeight <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Positive Weight.", , "Input Error")
    ElseIf decWeight > 30 Then
        MsgBox("You Have Entered " & decWeight.ToString() & ". Please Enter a Weight Under 30 Pounds", , "Input Error")
    End If


ElseIf txtWeight.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Enter the Weight", , "Input Error")

Else : MsgBox("Please Enter a Number", , "Input Error")
End If
```

Comment: Does `decWeight <= 30 > 0` supposed to be `decWeight <= 30 `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this if statement: If decWeight <= 30 and decWeight > 0 Then

This will check if the decWeight is less than or equal to 30 and make sure that it is 'non-zero' Hope this helps :-)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, although I don't understand why If decWeight <= 30 and decWeight > 0 Then works, but If decWeight <= 30 And decWeight > 0 Then doesn't. I thought it was the same thing? EDIT - Ah, I guess it isn't, and I do in fact have to include the And. Thanks!

Comment: Remember the old math rules, from left to right.  So is the result of "decWeight <= 30" greater than zero?  In VB, True = 1 and False = 0,

So if "decWeight <= 30"  is true, then "True > 0" is True.

As @riptide464c stated, you need to split your formula into 2 statements, and thus the AND.

Now it reads:  is the result of "decWeight <= 30" True AND is the result of "decWeight > 0" true?

Comment: So all of the other If statements need to be fixed as well.